# While loops and some help around it

Tags: python, loops

**Can someone help me with this piece of code ?**

*Write a  python program that shows the first 20 results of the hitting process in .7*

```
a=0
while a<=20:
    a+=1
    print(a*7)
```

Comment: What precisely is wrong with it? It seems to be fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does what it is supposed to. You just need to watch out how you indent it, try this:

```
a=0
while a<=20:
    a+=1
    print(a*7)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `for` instead of `while`

```
for n in range(1,21):
    print(n*7)
```

Or

```
[print(n*7) for n in range(1,21)]
```

For faster process